# How can I access the CiviCRM contact record 'group' value(s) of the current user?

Tags: civicrm

The unique key is email address. Perhaps there is a CiviCRM API?

**EDIT**

There is a CiviCRM API. My code so far:

```
civicrm_initialize();
$content = civicrm_api('contact', 'getvalue', array(
  'email' => $GLOBALS['user']->mail,
  'version' => 3,
  'return' => 'first_name')
);
```

I need the user's group, not first name.

Comment: Please do not edit answers into question. Post them as answers. I rolled back that edit, since it shouldn't happen.

Comment: I think you want to find all of the groupContact records for a given contact. See documentation at http://d45.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/api/doc#GroupContact

Answer (score 2):

You can even use 'email' api to get the contact id(as you have the email address in $GLOBALS['user']->mail) and then use 'GroupContact' api as above to get the groups record.

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Email', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => "contact_id",
  'email' => $GLOBALS['user']->mail,
));
```